# Get full URL path from browser with using ServerSocket and Socket classes

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm trying write my individual HTTP Server and I need a help .
What is the method of ServerSocket or Socket class can to invoke on the URL and brining it into a code.

For example, if I write following link `<b>http://localhost:8080/coupon/add?name=coupon name</b>` in browser, I would be want to get this link into my code.

Maybe who know how can I do this?

my simple code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class HTTPServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new HTTPServer().startServer();
    }

    public void startServer() {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080)) {

            System.out.println("Server is started");
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific/clarify - What about the link (as you state & list in original comment) are you trying to do with your web server? I ask because I don't understand if you're trying to create a web service from scratch (plenty of frameworks in existence today, e.g. Spring). Also note, there appears to be a query to service in your URL too - is this also part of the question?

Comment: What you're asking for is a http *client* not *server*.   You should probably use an existing client.   Either https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html or if you need more: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/  You are a very long ways away from writing your own http client.

Comment: The link `http://localhost:8080/coupon/add?name=coupon name` is a primitive link such as `https://www.google.com`, but with some sending parameters. Passing parameter it doesn't matter at the time there is not a problem for me

Comment: And yes, I will create an HTTP Server with web-service from scratch and it - a little bit of code it some example from my HTTP Server. At this time, I can't apply any technologies on server, it will be simple - how servlets.

Answer (score 8):

All your code does right now is set up a TCP server.

HTTP is a [Layer 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_7:_Application_Layer) protocol.

Once you accept the connection from the client, HTTP can be used for communication over that TCP socket.

You'd have to parse the HTTP request that the client sends, and from that, you'd know the URL.

In your case, you said:

> I write following link `http://localhost:8080/coupon/add?name=coupon name` in browser

Your browser will send an HTTP request like the following example:

```
GET /coupon/add?name=coupon+name HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost:8080
```

In reality, there will be more HTTP headers there, as well as a trailing `\r\n`, but for our sake, let's keep it simple.

Note that special characters like space are [URL-encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), however space is also encoded as `+` in the query string - it could be either `+` or `%20` depending on the client.

Hopefully it's reasonably clear to you from this explanation how you get the URL from this HTTP request.

The only missing part from the actual full link is the `http://` part.  The distinction between HTTP and HTTPS is not part of the HTTP protocol - it's above the socket layer but below the HTTP protocol layer.  If you had SSL sockets, you'd know that on the server side, and determine based on whether it was an SSL socket or a "plain" socket, whether it was `http` or `https`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But I have a problem to get links/data from browsers yet. Yes I understand about the Request and Response methods but I don't understand how can I get information from them.

Answer (score 2):

I improved for testing the `startServer` method for getting information.
I'm trying to include the data that comes from URL from any browsers to URI or URL class of JAVA. 
This impossible ? Maybe who know how can I do this ?

```
public void startServer() {
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080)) {

        System.out.println("Server is started");
        while (true) {

            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("SERVER SOCKET TESTS:");
            System.out.println("getChannel: " + serverSocket.getChannel());
            System.out.println("getInetAddress: " + serverSocket.getInetAddress());
            System.out.println("getLocalPort: " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
            System.out.println("getLocalSocketAddress: " + serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("CLIENT SOCKET TESTS:");
            System.out.println("getChannel: " + socket.getChannel());
            System.out.println("getLocalAddress: " + socket.getLocalAddress());
            System.out.println("getLocalPort: " + socket.getLocalPort());
            System.out.println("getLocalSocketAddress: " + socket.getLocalSocketAddress());
            System.out.println("getRemoteSocketAddress: " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            System.out.println("getInetAddress: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            System.out.println("getInputStream: " + socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("getOutputStream: " + socket.getOutputStream());

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("URI - GET INFORMATION:");
            URI uri = new URI("httpscheme://world.hello.com/thismy?parameter=value");
            System.out.println(uri.getHost());
            System.out.println(uri.getPath());
            System.out.println(uri.getQuery());
            System.out.println(uri.getScheme());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

little test:

[image]

when I run code and after that open the browser and I write in my browser, for example: `http://localhost:8080` I get information, but I don't understand following:
why the `serverSocket` object in `getInetAddress` method (`serverSocket.getInetAddress`) have an IP4 and it 0.0.0.0 (why not a standard local ip that defined on my computer) and the `socket` object of `getInetAddress` method (`socket.getInetAddress`) have an IP6 and it 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 . How can I get a standard host name `localhost` how to get the URI class (with chunks of data of link)?

The port is gated nice: 8080.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for getting URL path , solved.

---

```
    package pk6HttpServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by Morris on 08/10/16.
 */
public class HTTPServer {

    private static String headerData;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new HTTPServer().startServer();
    }

    public void startServer() {

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080)) {

            boolean isClosed = false;

            System.out.println("Server is started");

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                try {
                    try (InputStream raw = socket.getInputStream()) { // ARM

                        System.out.println("=================BEFORE STARTING READING HEADER =======================");

                        System.out.println("Collecting data to string array...");

                        headerData = getHeaderToArray(raw);
//
                        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++ AFTER ENDING READING HEADER +++++++++++++++++++++++");
                        System.out.println("Hello World");
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    System.err.println(socket.getLocalAddress() + " is not a parseable URL");

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error# " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String getHeaderToArray(InputStream inputStream) {

        String headerTempData = "";

        // chain the InputStream to a Reader
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        try {
            int c;
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) c);
                headerTempData += (char) c;

                if (headerTempData.contains("\r\n\r\n"))
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        headerData = headerTempData;

        return headerTempData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The path is found in the first line of your client request header, after GET. You can parse the first header line and extract it, something like this

```
  InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
  InputStreamReader(inputStream));

  // header first line
  String requestLine = reader.readLine();

  // get path
  String[] requestLineArray = requestLine.split("\\s+");
  filePath = requestLineArray[1];
```