# How to create GET endpoint in plain Java?

Tags: java

My goal is to learn how to create a GET endpoint with plain Java.

My expected result is: I can send a GET request using a browser or using the Postman.

My actual result: localhost:8080 refused to connect. The Java application process finished with exit code 0 after I sent the GET request.

This is the code that I am currently using.

```
package httpserver;

import httpserver.config.Configuration;
import httpserver.config.ConfigurationManager;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class HttpServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Server starting...");

    ConfigurationManager.getInstance().loadConfigurationFile("src/main/resources/http.json");
    Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getCurrentConfiguration();

    System.out.printf("Using Port: %s%n" +
            "Using WebRoot: %s%n", conf.getPort(), conf.getWebroot());

    try {
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(conf.getPort());
      Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

      InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
      OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

      String html = "<html>" +
              "<head>" +
              "<title>Simple Java HTTP Server</title>" +
              "</head>" +
              "<body>" +
              "<p>This page was server using my Simple Java HTTP Server</p>" +
              "</body>" +
              "</html>";

      final String CRLF = "\n\r"; // 13, 10

      String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CRLF + // Status Line : HTTP_VERSION RESPONSE_CODE RESPONSE_MESSAGE
              "Content-Length: " + html.getBytes().length + CRLF + CRLF + // end of HEADER
              html +
              CRLF + CRLF;

      outputStream.write(response.getBytes());

      inputStream.close();
      outputStream.close();
      socket.close();
      serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After checking, it turns out the CRLF is reversed. It should be `\r\n`.

Comment: This will help you out further - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886969/get-full-url-path-from-browser-with-using-serversocket-and-socket-classes

Answer (score 1):

You code is finishing after serving the first connection. You need to enclose the accept in a loop, for example:

```
public class HttpServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Server starting...");

    ConfigurationManager.getInstance().loadConfigurationFile("src/main/resources/http.json");
    Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getCurrentConfiguration();

    System.out.printf("Using Port: %s%n" +
            "Using WebRoot: %s%n", conf.getPort(), conf.getWebroot());

    try {
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(conf.getPort());

      while (true) { // Infinte loop
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();


        String response = ...;

        outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        socket.close();
      }
      serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```